# lein custom java class not found exception

Tags: java, clojure, classpath, leiningen

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` when I import my custom java class in my clojure project.

```
;project.clj
(defproject subclass "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :main subclass.core
  :aot [subclass.core]
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})

;src/subclass/core.clj
(ns subclass.core
    (:gen-class
     :extends BaseClass
     :exposes-methods {greet pgreet})
    (:import BaseClass))  ;This is being qualified as java.lang.BaseClass

(defn -main [& args])

//src/java/BaseClass.java
public class BaseClass {
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello from BaseClass";
    }
}
```

When I run `lein repl` I am getting the following error:

```
Compiling subclass.core
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.BaseClass, compiling:(subclass/core.clj:1:1)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.BaseClass, compiling:(subclas
s/core.clj:1:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6875)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
        ... snip ...
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Baseclass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:69)
        ... snip ...
        ... 54 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

The `BaseClasss` is getting qualified as `java.lang.BaseClass` which fails. How will refer BaseClass from `src/java`? Thanks.

Comment: `Baseclass` is not the same thing as `BaseClass`.

Comment: Sorry, updated the post.

Comment: Alan Thompson: Thanks, that works.

Comment: @AlanThompson Please write this in an answer so we can close that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `BaseClass` in a package. Java & Clojure don't like "naked" classes.